# Update master branch on merge

Tags: php, laravel, git, gitlab

I have a Laravel project running on an EC2 instance that is the master branch of my gitlab repo.

I want to merge a branch to the master. Does the live project running on the EC2 instance update automatically upon merge or do I have to do something to trigger the changes?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is [pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/) in your gitlab who do it for you (e.g rebuild application) every changes for example in master branch.